# Kickstart HTML5 database

Tags: iphone, html

I have an HTML5 application that is wrapped on a native client (iPhone).  When the app starts, is it possible to copy a database (SQLite) into place so the browser can use?

Answer (score 0):

Being able to place files directly onto the user's storage is usually restricted from web apps, unless your native client wrapper provides a ready made API you would have to write your own extension method.

You could use the SQLite dump command to create a SQL backup (see under heading [Converting An Entire Database To An ASCII Text File](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html)):

```
echo '.dump' | sqlite3 ex1 >ex1.dump
```

Then just pass the entire thing as a string to [`executeSql`](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#dom-sqltransaction-executesql).

Comment: I like the idea, but wondering if the resource, say the export file, was embedded in my wrapper, if there is a way to write to the HTML5 database from an iPhone app directly without needing to use javascript.

Comment: @RobBonner As I said, you'd need an API in your native client wrapper to place files on the device.  I'm more familiar with Android than iOS so I don't know if that's possible.